# How to read list in django template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Could someone shed a light to help me to solve this nested list problem in Django template.
I come across a list as such

[['Summary 1 CODE018'], [['Directory/File Name', 'Result']], [[['dir/var1/file1.txt', 'pass'], ['dir/var2/file2.txt', 'pass'], ['dir/var1/file3', 'pass']]], [[['null']]]]

How do I loop the above list so that I can get a table such as the first index is the table title, index1 is the table title and the rest (except when is it null) is the table body? Please take note that the last item could be [[['null']]] or [[['null', 'Info on directory CODEA18']]] which should be skip when null is detected.

Expected table:

```
Directory/File Name     Result
dir/var1/file1.txt      pass
dir/var2/file2.txt      pass
dir/var3/file3.txt      pass
```

My faulty code as below

```
    <table id="myTable">
        {% for list in summary %}
            <tr>
                <td> {{ list.0 }} </td>
            <tbody>
                <td> {{ list.0.0 }} </td>
                <td> {{ list.0.0.0 }} </td>
            </tbody>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: can you upload the sample table

Comment: Sure.. I updated my post

Comment: the last [[['null']]]] where to add that

Comment: The flow should skip the line when it see 'null' and that usually happen only on the final index of the list. Thanks NavaneethaKrishnan for looking into this.

Comment: i hope the whole thing is enclosed by a single list. if som, there should 2 more closing bracket at the end.[[['null']]]]]].. is this correct.. 5 brackets at the end..

Comment: no, the list is just as what I have shown

Comment: That is throwing a syntax error for me. actually the list is not closed.

Comment: Sorry, I amended the data, can you try it again? Missing 2 square bracket after the final 'pass'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You list have 4 items. In that 2nd is Table heading and 3rd is table row.
We need to run 2 loops, one for `thead` and one for `tbody`

```
<table border>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        {% for i in a[1][0] %}
            <th>{{i}}</th>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for i in a[2][0] %}
        <tr>
            {% for j in i%}
            <td>{{j}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, you do me a great favor. Now a get clearer picture. I did minor modification changing a[1][0] to a.1.0 as a[1][0] doesn't works for me. Not sure why. Can you please help me on my another issue. I mentioned it in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64893006/to-generate-a-table-from-a-nested-list-in-django-template . Out of idea how to solve that too.